# how to combine the function to get the info of certain studid

Tags: php

heres my code

```
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
$studId = $_REQUEST['studid'];
foreach ($studId as $ch){
echo $ch."<br>";
}
}
//the result of this is like this
c-1111
c-1112
c-1113
// but i want to know their names
```

i have a function to get the studinfo shown below. how would i apply/insert this in the above code to get the names of those stuid's..pls help

```
function getuserinfo($ch){
$info_select = "SELECT `$ch` FROM `tbl_student` WHERE `studId`='$ch'";
if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { 
if ($result = mysql_result($query_get, 0, $ch)) {
return $result;
}
}
}
$fname = getuserinfo('fname');
$lname = getuserinfo('lname');
$mname = getuserinfo('mname');
```

Comment: What doeso the code help with?

Comment: @WilliamN... to know the names of those studid's

Answer (score 0):

This is wildly dangerous as is, but here is the basic idea:
Your current query inexplicably fetches the student id where student id equals the passed value. So that looks like it is just trying to verify, but it is unnecessary. You want to return all info, then replace the first $ch with just * to fetch all...

```
function getuserinfo($ch){
    $info_select = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_student` WHERE `studId`='$ch'";
    if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { 
        if ($result = mysql_result($query_get, 0, $ch)) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

You call it by passing the id:

```
getuserinfo($ch);
```

You can then access all student info for the row. try `var_dump(getuserinfo($ch))` to see what's returned if this makes no sense.

But you are just fetching RAW from $_REQUEST with absolutely no cleansing. You are wide open to attack this way.

Switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements. This answer is just to explain how ot get the info. In no way do I condone the use of these deprecated methods as is.

*edit*

As per your comment, you need to access the result to do something like that...

```
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $studId = $_REQUEST['studid'];
    $where = "";
    foreach ($studId as $ch){
        $where .= "studId = '$ch' OR";
    }
    if(strlen($where) > 0)
    {
        $where = substr($where, 0, -2);
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT studId, CONCAT(fname, " ", mname, " ",lname) AS name FROM tbl_student WHERE $where");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['name'].'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

...again, sanitize the input. It's not being done in this example. This is just to give an idea

Comment: i still got an error, it says that not found(the last studid is selected) in MySQL result index 6 in if ($result = mysql_result($query_get, 0, $ch))

Comment: what about like this,   if(isset($_POST['select']))  {  $studId = $_REQUEST['studid'];    foreach ($studId as $ch)  {  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tbl_student.studId, tbl_student.fname, tbl_student.lname, tbl_student.mname FROM tbl_student WHERE studId = '$ch'");   echo $ch."<br/>";   }  }

Comment: I updated. no promises there but sure - there's no reason technically why you can't just query the students in that conditional unless $mysqli is out of scope. One way to know - try it out.

Comment: i change my variable $studId into $studId = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_REQUEST['studid'])); but 
 i still got an error on this...it says "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given " and an error saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in this line foreach($studId as $ch).